# Generate javascript in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget, embed

Im making a embedable widget and i need to generate a unique JavaScript snippet for the user to copy past into there site. For simplicity i killed most of the code.

widget-generator.js

```
.directive('widgetGenerate',function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'embed.html', // file i need to generate
            scope: {
                "height": "@"
            }
        };
    });
```

embed.html

```
<a height='{{height}}'> // WORKS!
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var something = {{height}}; // DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
</script>
```

On page for user to copy past:

```
<textarea>
  <widget-generate height = '300'/>
</textarea>
```

Desired text output:

```
 <a height='300'> </a>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var something = 300; 
 </script>
```

Problem is i cannot generate the JavaScript section like this. How can i do this in angularjs?

Comment: Instead of including the javascript in your template, can you set what you want on $window in a controller for the directive? $window.something = $scope.height;

Comment: the textarea needs to display in plain text the final javascript code, if i use your method the final code would look like this: var something = $window.something; instead of var something = 300;

Comment: So you don't want the code to run? Just display?

Comment: yes thats the plan, if possible both would be nice

Comment: Have you tried escaping the template? "<" -> "&lt;", ">" -> "&gt;", etc.

Comment: works! thanks for the help, make an answer for it.

Comment: No problem, please mark as accepted if this was enough to help you onwards, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/u9b69zh6/1/) for it to get you in the right direction.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <widget-generate height="300"></widget-generate>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('widgetGenerate',[function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template:   '<textarea>' + 
                      '&lt;a height="{{height}}"&gt;\r\n' +
                      '&lt;/a&gt;\r\n' +
                      '&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;\r\n' +
                      '\tvar something = {{height}};\r\n' +
                      '&lt;/script&gt;' +
                    '</textarea>',
        scope: {
            "height": "@"
        }
    };
}]);
```